# Custom parameters in Module_Json (Business Catalyst)

Tags: javascript, json, business-catalyst

{Module_JSON} allow you to parse json files in Business Catalyst, however, there is NO documentation, or functionality to utilize the data using liquid. I tried talking to support, but they said that my questions were out of the support boundaries.

Here is what I would like to do: I would like to call specific items within an array via Json.

```
{
  "description": "List of a collection of Doughnuts",
  "doughnuts": [
    {
      "id": "5001",
      "type": "Plain",
      "price": 0
    },
    {
      "id": "5002",
      "type": "Glazed",
      "price": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "5005",
      "type": "Sugar",
      "price": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "5007",
      "type": "Powdered Sugar",
      "price": 1.25
    },
    {
      "id": "5006",
      "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles",
      "price": 1.5
    },
    {
      "id": "5003",
      "type": "Chocolate",
      "price": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "5004",
      "type": "Maple Syrup",
      "price": 2.25
    }
  ]
}
```

To parse the JSON you have to do this:

```
{module_json,json="/mrbean.json" template="/module_json/template.tpl"}
```

Let's say I would like to parse the plain donut, I would try and put the parameter right in the callback function like this:

```
{module_json,json="/mrbean.json" type="plain" template="/module_json/template.tpl"}
```

Nothing happens. Does anyone know how I can do this? Otherwise, I don't see why the Module_Json tag should be used. Should I just use Ajax instead?

Answer (score 0):

There is a rather clear example here http://docs.businesscatalyst.com/Developers/liquid/render-your-own-JSON-files-using-module_json
If you need any help please post here.

Please include some more explanation in your question.

Do you have a template created?
Please post your template so I can check your syntax.

If your data rendered with json looks like this `{
   "description":"List of a collection of Products",
   "products":[
      {
         "id":"SLI123",
         "type":"Toy",
         "price":20
      },
      {
         "id":"SLI124",
         "type":"Shirt",
         "price":40
      },`

then you liquid rendering can be something like this

```
<div>{{this.description}}</div>
<ul>   {%; for products in this.products %}
    <li id={{product.id}} type={{product.type}}>
        {%; if product.price == 20 %}
           Price: Only ${{product.price}}!!!

{%; else %}
            Price: ${{product.price}}
        {%; endif %}
    </li>
    {%; endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The tag makes no assumptions about how the json is structured. This allows it to load any valid json, but puts the onus on the caller to handle the data within.

In this case, you could use the `collection` parameter to assign it to a variable, like so:

```
{module_json,json="/mrbean.json" collection="food"}
{{ food.doughnuts[0].type }} <!-- Plain -->
```

(The same data is available within the named file, when using the `template` parameter.)

---

> Otherwise, I don't see why the Module_Json tag should be used. Should I just use Ajax instead?

If it better suits your application to have the user make another round-trip after page load to see the data, then use ajax / fetch.
If the app should load with the data as quickly as possible, then `module_json` can insert the data into the first response.